# What are qubits made of in Wen's string-net theory?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, topological-order

In Prof. Xiaogang Wen's theory, photons and electrons are described as quasi-particles appeared as a result of the existence of the string-net liquid, which is the topological order of the qubits that form the space. This is a little confusing to me. Consider when we talk about other quasi-particles, for example, phonons, we say they are excitons appear from the oscillation of the atoms that form the solid, which means that 'atoms' are 'real' while phonons are 'quasi-particles'. But when we make an analogy between photon and phonon, (topological order with lattice model, qubit with atoms), what are those qubit in essence? Are they some kind of ultimate thing that build up our world?

Answer (score 8):

**What are those qubit in essence? Are they some kind of ultimate thing that build up our world?**

Yes. In the string-net picture of elementary particles, the qubits are the ultimate things that build up our world. We live inside a quantum qubit world (ie a quantum information world) 
(see http://blog.sciencenet.cn/blog-1116346-736093.html )

Such an emergence approach has a falsifiable prediction: The 123 standard model is incomplete. The correct theory must contain an extra discrete gauge theory which leads to new cosmic strings.
[see http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1281
    *Topological order: from long-range entangled quantum matter to an unification of light and electrons* （section IV D)]